# ADD instruction or plus sign?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Very simble question, yet I didn't find a good answer so I'm asking here.
I see that sometimes for addition we use the ADD instruction, and sometimes I see the use of the plus sign (+).
Please look at the following:

```
mov eax,[esi + TYPE DWORD]
```

Well, I learned that for adding numbers I should use the ADD instruction, yet it seems to work like this.
I thought it should have been done this way:

```
add esi, TYPE DWORD
mov eax,[esi]
sub esi, TYPE DWORD
```

I mean, how can the computer access the memory address *esi + TYPE DWORD* without doing an add instruction? so odd...
Thank you so much for reading (:

Comment: [CISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing)?

Comment: Don't fall into the trap of thinking 1 mnemonic = 1 instruction = 1 cycle.

Comment: @OllieFord it *is* one instruction though, and if it was a `lea` it would have been a single-cycle instruction

Comment: @OllieFord so the second code (with ADD and SUB) is what the processor truly executes?

Comment: No. It will put the value of `esi` and 4 (type dword is 4) through an adder. It doesn't need instructions for that, just an adder. Just like how it doesn't execute an `add eip, instruction_length`. It can't be turtles all the way down, at some point it's just silicon circuitry.

Comment: Your example phrase `esi + TYPE DWORD` doesn't actually add anything to `esi` -- that is, after executing this, `esi` is unchanged. As such you can observe it is not a *real* addition. (It is -- but not inside the same scope as `add`.) Even just an `add eax, 0` "does" something you can observe: it influences the flags register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, these are encoded as two different things - the `ADD` is an instruction, will come with a full opcode, while the `+` will be translated by your assembler into referencing mode for the main instruction it's attached to (`MOV` in this case).

The main difference however is that the first will be performed by the memory unit (or more accurately - the address generation unit), without consuming any additional arbitration on top of the load execution, while the latter will be performed over the ALU, and consume the required resources accordingly (depending on the micro architecture, but in your example, on any modern out-of-order CPU that would take at least a few queue entries, decode slots, scheduling slots, ports, etc..).

In that sense the first is often "cheaper", which is why it's often used even for normal arithmetic operations without memory referencing, by using a `LEA` instruction, as Harold pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

To go a little more generic, what you are looking at in the first example is part of the addressing mode, not an op-code.

The simplest form of address registers is simply a pointer to what you're interested in (the base address)

```
[bx]
```

If you were looking at an array or a structure then you would have to adjust the base register to look at anything else. Time moved on and addressing became more flexible. You could have a base and an index:

```
[ebx+eax]    ; add 2 registers to get the pointers - array + index
```

Now, if you have an array of bytes you can keep the base and adjust the index. If you are looking at 2, 4 or 8 bytes you can adjust the index by the size of the target:

```
[ebx+eax*2]   ; 2 byte target, array + (index*2)
```

Now, if you're looking at a c-style structure then you can add a displacement to the resulting address, too:

```
[ebx+eax*2+16]
```

These are encoded into the instruction at compile time, not turned into assembler instructions. Familiarize yourself with addressing modes - they will save you a lot of time if you use the right mode for the right solution.